# Google Appengine - 2 Way TLS Authentication

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

I have a python application deployed on top of google appengine standard environment.
I want to enable two way SSL/TLS on top of my application so that only trusted clients can actually interact with my application.

I am not able to find any concrete resources / documentation around the same. Has anyone implemented it in the past who can suggest the way out?

Answer (score 1):

App Engine does not support Two-way TLS (Mutual TLS).

App Engine offers built-in load balancing. First paragraph in [1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) says "SSL support for your App Engine app goes above and beyond basic SSL by offering globally-distributed SSL endpoints and built-in load balancing to serve your app securely, reliably, and quickly to a worldwide audience".

Load balancers don't suppert mutual TLS: "Google Cloud load balancers don't support client certificate-based authentication (mutual TLS, mTLS)" [2](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#ssl-certificate-limits).

There are these alternatives:

- GKE with Istio ([3](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/security/), [4](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/)).
- AppEngine with Apigee Edge [5](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/system-administration/keystores-and-truststores).

---

Comment: I'm glad this helped you, and hope the Apigee approach works well!

Comment: Google now supports mTLS for load balancers [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/mtls) but mTLS support is [preGA](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#1).